# Calculating Field to six digit number from another field concatenated with State Plane code in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, error-000732, error-000539

I'm trying to calculate a field (Unique_ID) in arcpy that will bring in a six digit number from another field (Point_ID) in the table.  I want to add the state plane code to the end of the Point_ID and have it calculate in the Unique_ID code.

I tried copying it from a python snipped to get what I want and this is what it gave me.

```
 arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON","Unique_ID","!PointID!","PYTHON","")
```

I also have a string of all the state plane codes.  I need to get the end of the state plane code added to the end of the PointID.
[image]

New Code just trying the "!PointID!"
[image]
Giving me this error:
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset SMON does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

I set the environment to the database doing the calcs and ended up working for just the !PointID! part of the script.  When I try to add ,+ "PointID!" + Con , it kicks back:  ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

Comment: What happens when you execute the code?

Comment: PointID is not defined.

Comment: from your description you call the field "Point_ID" and in the code you have it as "PointID."  Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Sorry, it's PointID in the script and the table.  I messed it up writing in here.

Comment: `arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON", "Unique_ID", "\"PointID\" + \" 1111\"", "PYTHON")`

Comment: try the formatting above to see if it works

Comment: That outputs the string into the Unique_ID.  This is what it says in the field "PointIDCon"

Where Con = 0501

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12620/discussion-between-detroit-hc-and-joebob)

Comment: With this many Comments and Answers plus Chat it seems clear that the edit button should be used to try and revise your Question into something much clearer.  If you do that then be sure to include your code (copy/paste, select and hit Code button) rather than a picture of it.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution may be to use a cursor:

arcpy.UpdateCursor - (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000)

Calculate Field is nice for in-application use (i.e. changing field values in ArcMap/Catalog or model builder, but cursors are much more powerful (and easier to use) when accessing attribute data in code. Try this...

```
    urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Point_Layer)
    for urow in urows:
        urow.StatePlane = 'Colorado North'
        urow.State = 'Colorado'
        urow.UniqueID = str(urow.PointID) + 'Con'
        urows.updateRow(urow)

    del urow, urows
```

Comment: +1 for using an update cursor instead. However, since the OP is using 10.1, I'd go with the [arcpy.da version](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) instead.

Comment: Good point, @nmpeterson. While 'arcpy.UpdateCursor' will still work, 'arcpy.da.UpdateCursor' is much faster and an even better option.

Comment: what is the advantage to using arcpy.da?

Comment: @joebob I find arcpy.da is about 10X faster so I always use that over old style cursors if given the option.

Comment: @joebob Yes, `arcpy.da` all the way. It has better support for closing properly with `with` statements. Not to mention the speed improvements and other various parameters that wasn't previously possible.

Comment: @joebob - as PolyGeo and Paul mentioned, there are speed and other functional improvements introduced with arcpy.da. This document helps explain the benefits of using arcpy.da in more detail [Introducing the ArcPy Data Access Module](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit12/papers/introducing_the_arcpy_data_access_module.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```py
arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON", "Unique_ID", "!PointID! + \" 1111\"", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: This returns PointIDCON in the Unique_ID field.

Comment: yep, my bad it should be !PointID!

Comment: I get an error saying invalid syntax if it just goes in as !PointID!.

Comment: If I put quotes around it "!PointID!" it says ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset SMON does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Answer (score 0):

The names of the fields with Python need to be between `"!"`. So if you write your code in Python, it should be :

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Point_Layer, "Unique_ID", "!PointID! + 'Con' ", "PYTHON")
```

or, if `PointID` is not a text field,

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Point_Layer, "Unique_ID", "str(!PointID!) + 'Con' ", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: `arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON", "Unique_ID", "!PointID! + '1111'", "PYTHON")`

Comment: All of the fields are strings.  I still can't get it to just run the "PointID".

Comment: is the size of Unique_ID large enough to store the result ? Have you tried doing it from the field calculator in ArcMap ? Are your field "visible" when you make the feature layer ?

Comment: Yes, here is the exact python snipped I get with adding "111" at the end:    # Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "SMON"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON","Unique_ID","""!PointID!+"1111"""","PYTHON_9.3","#")

Comment: I can just use !PointID! too and it returns this:  # Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "SMON"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON","Unique_ID","!PointID!","PYTHON_9.3","#")

Comment: I just tried to add "_9.3" to the end of 'PYTHON' and that didn't work either.  This is what it continues to kick back to me.....:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Scripts\Survey Calaculate Database Field for State Plane.py", line 62, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("SMON", "Unique_ID", "!PointID!" , "PYTHON_9.3", "#")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3129, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset SMON does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: the problem seems to come from SMON (probably the workspace is not set, so it is not found, you should use "point_layer" instead.

Comment: Set the environement before changing the "SMON" and it ended up changing all of the Unique_IDs with PointIDs.  Not a big deal.  Changed the "SMON" back to Point_Layer.  Now I can finally get the !PointID! to show up in the Unique_ID field.  Now I just need to figure out how to add the variable Con to the end of the !PointID!.  I tried ,"!PointID!" + Con, and that didn't seem to work. Here is the error.

Comment: ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: please look at my answer. when you do "!PointID!" + Con, your are in your main python script, and this is what is interpreted first. You need to send a string to the arcgis tool, and this string will be interpreted by the field calculator (Python or vb). for instance, "!uniqueID!" + "Con" is like writing !uniqueID!Con in the field calculator within arcmap. What you need is either [PointID] & 'Con' (for VB concatenation) or !PointID! + 'Con' (for PYTHON concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

```
urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Point_Layer)
for urow in urows:
    urow.StatePlane = 'Colorado North'
    urow.State = 'Colorado'
    urow.Unique_ID = str(urow.PointID) + str(Con)
    urows.updateRow(urow)

del urow, urows
```

Thanks!!  This ended up working.  UpdateCursor is much cleaner.  I'm new so python new commands are fun to learn.

Comment: This looks identical to the code provided by @DonnRK.  If I have not overlooked a key difference I think you should hit the green tick to Accept that Answer, and then delete this one.  Your last sentence could be added as a Comment to that Accept-ed Answer if you wish too.